# MySQL SELECT first letter of the words sequentially for searching

Tags: php, mysql, regex, match

**Sample words:**

```
iknkr st nm krt prk
iknkr vhgr j k pth  
iknkr hkm st
iknkr sr vhgr j k pth
```

**Required Condition**

Now, if a user types: `ik s` the query will return:

```
iknkr st nm krt prk 
iknkr sr vhgr j k pth
```

---

if a user types: `i v` the query will return:

```
iknkr vhgr j k pth
```

**Currently Trying:**

```
SELECT `walpha` AS word, pageID AS id 
FROM `SX01` 
WHERE `table`= 'S01' 
  AND `walpha` like '" . $this->db->escape_like_str($searchVal['keyword']) . "%' 
LIMIT 100"
```

But using this user have to type: `iknkr s`

to get the result

```
iknkr st nm krt prk 
iknkr sr vhgr j k pth
```

Can anyone suggest, what will be the right way of doing it.

Comment: Can you explain the logic? if user type `ik` you want words that contain or start with `ik` ?

Comment: start with `ik`, but search will start from first word, if a user type `ik s vb n`, then it will match `ik` from first word, `s` from second word, `vb` from third word and `n` from fourth word, and show the results based on that

Comment: So if two words like `ik s`, first word need to start with `ik` and second word with `s` ?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza OP wants that each string user inputs is matched against a word in his strings. So "AA BB" means that first word in the string must start wit AA and the second with BB. this at least is my best guess on this confusing post

Comment: Yes that is what I want @LelioFaieta

Comment: @LelioFaieta You dont have to guess. If question isnt clear you wait for OP to clear the issues, otherwise you waste your time answer the wrong question ;)

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I'm on coffee break and trying a new kind of crossword puzzle ;)

Comment: @LelioFaieta mmm what that mean?

Comment: @LelioFaieta Also you're completly write, its what he's asking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could build a [regular expression](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/pattern-matching.html) from the input and then use [REGEXP](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html) to have MySQL use it. For example, you could turn `ik s` into `^ik[a-z]* s` to match words which which start with `ik` followed by a word starting with `s`...

```
SELECT words FROM tbl WHERE t.words REGEXP '^ik[a-z]* s';
```

- `^` means we must match from the start of the string
- `ik` must then be the first two chars
- `[a-z]` will match any lowercase alphabetic char
- `*` allows us to match zero or more of the previous pattern - i.e. any sequence of chars can follow `ik`
- then must have a space
- `s` followed by an s - we don't care about what follows.

You can build this pattern from the user input by replacing all spaces with `[a-z]*` and prefixing with `^`

Comment: regular expression are very hard for me. Why you dont have to include `s*` to indicate anything else?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza : the `*` signs indicates anything after ik 
and `[a-z]` means it can be any alphabetical chars . query is working fine

Comment: `s*` would mean 'zero or more s chars' which isn't what you want. You just want to be sure the next work starts with s, and not care about the rest.

Comment: @prakashtank I understand the first `*` my question is why `s` doesnt need `*`.

Comment: OK, I got it now. Is different from DOS command like `dir myfile.*`

Comment: The problem with this answer is how you use user input to update your query?

Comment: break the input on spaces and build the regex yourself. Exercise for the reader :)

You could build the regex with MySQL string replacement and concatenation operations too.

Comment: I am able to resolve the issue using your suggestion - `"SELECT \`walpha\` AS word, \`pageID\` AS id FROM \`SX01\` WHERE \`table\`= 'S01' AND \`walpha\` regexp concat('^', replace('" . $this->db->escape_like_str($searchVal['keyword']) . "', ' ', '[a-z]* ')) LIMIT 100"` +1 @PaulDixon

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your logic correctly, you could try with a query like this:

```
select `walpha` AS word, pageID AS id
from `SX01` 
where
  `table`= 'S01' 
  and `walpha` like concat(replace('" . $yoursearchval . "', ' ', '% '), '%') 
limit 100
```

for example:

```
concat(replace('i k', ' ', '% '), '%')
```

will become:

```
i% k%
```

but if you want the words to be consecutive, you'll have to use a regular expression:

```
where whalpa regexp concat('^', replace('i k', ' ', '[^[:space:]]+ '))
```

and i k will become:

```
^i[^[:space:]]+ k
```

- the string has to start with i
- after i there has to be at least + one non space character
- then one space
- then one k
- then anything else

Comment: That would match `iknkr zzzz ssss` which might not be what the OP wanted - it doesn't ensure that the *second* word will start with s

Comment: @PaulDixon yes you're right, i've just updated my answer, thank you

Comment: I was doing your split strings to [rows](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17942691/3470178) but fiddle doesnt work :(

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza sqlfiddle looks down at the moment... anyway I included the fiddle in the answer, second part, so you can try it on your own server if you wish

Comment: Yes, I move it to rextester, but wasnt working for a typo. Is fix now.

Answer (score 0):

select id,title,upper(left(title,1)) AS FirstLetter from store order by title